# Given that $f(k, x) = \frac{1}{k^{x}} \sum_{i = 1}^{x}{{(-1)}^{i - 1}k^{i}}$, is it true that $|\lim_{x \to \infty}{f(k, x)}| = \frac{k}{k + 1}$?

Tags: limits

Given that:

$$f(k, x) = \frac{1}{k^{x}} \sum_{i = 1}^{x}{{(-1)}^{i - 1}k^{i}}$$

is it true that:

$$|\lim_{x \to \infty}{f(k, x)}| = \frac{k}{k + 1}$$

According to Desmos Graphing Calculator, this seems to be true, but I am unsure as to how to (dis)prove it.

Comment: Note that $|\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{f(k, x)}|$ does not exist because $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{f(k, x)}$ does not exist, but that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}|{f(k, x)}|$ does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true (provided $k > 1$).  We have \begin{align*}
|f(k,x)| &= \left|\frac{1}{k^x} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^x (-1)^{i - 1}k^i\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{-k}{k^x}\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{x - 1} (-k)^i\right| \\
&=  \left|\frac{-k}{k^x}\left(\frac{1 - (-k)^x}{1 + k} \right)\right|\\
&= \frac{\left|k - \frac{1}{k^{x - 1}}\right|}{1 + k} \\
&\to \frac{k}{1 + k} \quad\text{   as }x \to \infty
\end{align*}

Comment: isn't that if $k\geq 1$ from the second to last step? Otherwise the term blows up.

Comment: @izœc, Yes, good catch.  I'll add that in.  We need $k > 1$, in fact, otherwise it blows up or is equal to $0$ (in the case where $k = 1$).

Comment: Yes, that's right - I didn't look at the original expression, but if $k=1$ then the series is just alternating between $+1$ and $0$, and hence doesn't converge in the limit, so certainly $k>1$.